# How to split and export the mysql code into other file and can be use anywhere in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs, express

I'm new in Reactjs. Its been 2 months since I learned Reactjs. I have a question. How to split the mysql code that i created into 2 file and can be call it anywhere. Here i attached the mysql code.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mysql = require('mysql');
const cors = require('cors');
const { response } = require('express');

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json()); //convert from json

// configure database 
const db = mysql.createConnection({
  user: 'root',
  host: 'localhost',
  password: '',
  database: 'testdb',
});


// declare function
function getQuery(db, sqlQuery, res) {
  db.query(sqlQuery, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      res.send(err.sqlMessage);
    } else {
      res.send(result);
    }
  });
}

function setQuery(db, sqlQuery, par, res) {
  db.query(sqlQuery, par, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      res.send(err);
    } else {
      res.send(result);
    }
  });
}

// configure server port number
const listener = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3333, () => {
  console.log('App is listening on port ' + listener.address().port)
})

// call function
app.get("/users", (req, res) => {
  getQuery(db, displayTableQuery, res)
});

app.post("/", (req, res) => {
  const RegisterUserQuery = "INSERT INTO users set ?";
  const par = req.body;
  setQuery(db, RegisterUserQuery, par, res)
});
```

The code i want to be in other file:

```
// call function
app.get("/users", (req, res) => {
  getQuery(db, displayTableQuery, res)
});

app.post("/", (req, res) => {
  const RegisterUserQuery = "INSERT INTO users set ?";
  const par = req.body;
  setQuery(db, RegisterUserQuery, par, res)
});
```

How to make the code above in other file so that i can make it globally use for other person in the project. Thank you so much for your time. Hope you guys can help me :(

Answer (score 1):

Create other file, example mysqlDatabase.js. And write in that file :

```
// configure database 
const db = mysql.createConnection({
  user: 'root',
  host: 'localhost',
  password: '',
  database: 'testdb',
});

module.exports = db
```

Then to access in other file, use require and write function without db as argument :

```
const db = require('./mysqlDatabase.js')

// declare function
function getQuery(sqlQuery, res) {
  db.query(sqlQuery, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      res.send(err.sqlMessage);
    } else {
      res.send(result);
    }
  });
}

function setQuery(sqlQuery, par, res) {
  db.query(sqlQuery, par, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      res.send(err);
    } else {
      res.send(result);
    }
  });
}
```